# JSON dependent dynamic dropdown third level array error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have three dropdowns which are depend on each other. Based on the selection of Dropdown A will have a list of results in Dropdown B, and based on the selection of Dropdown B will have a list of results in Dropdown C.

I can populate the first two dropdowns without a problem. However the last dropdown does shows me incorrect options.

```js
$(function() {
  var platforms;
  var tasktypes;
  var compos;
  var jsonData;
    
  $('#addnew').click(function(){
  $('#dataset').clone().appendTo($('#newfield'));
  });

  $.getJSON('tasks.json', function(result) {
    jsonData = result;

    $.each(result, function(i, platform) {
    platforms += "<option value='" +
      platform.name +
      "'>" +
      platform.name +
      "</option>";
    });
    $('#platform').html(platforms);
  });

  $("#platform").change(function (){
    var idx = $("#platform").prop('selectedIndex');
    var platforms = jsonData[idx].task;

    tasktypes = "";
    for (i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
      tasktypes += "<option value='" +
        platforms[i].taskname +
        "'>" +
        platforms[i].taskname +
        "</option>";
    };
  $('#taskname').html(tasktypes);
});
    
    
$("#taskname").change(function (){
    var idc = $("#taskname").prop('selectedIndex');
    var tasktypes = jsonData[idc].task[0].component;

    compos = "";
    for (i = 0; i < tasktypes.length; i++) {
      compos += "<option value='" +
        tasktypes[i].componentname +
        "'>" +
        tasktypes[i].componentname +
        "</option>";
    };
  $('#components').html(compos);
});


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="addnew">Add new</button>

<div id="dataset">
Platform:
<select id="platform">
</select>
Task Type:
<select id="taskname">
</select>
Component:
<select id="components">
</select>
Units:
<input type="number" min="0" />
</div>

<div id="newfield"></div>

<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Json**

```
[
{
    "name": "Sitecore",
    "value": "sitecore",
    "task": [
        {
            "taskname": "promobox",
            "component": [
                {
                    "componentname": "A",
                    "time": "20"
      },
                {
                    "componentname": "B",
                    "time": "10"
      }
    ]
  },
        {
            "taskname": "video",
            "component": [
                {
                    "componentname": "C",
                    "time": "20"
      },
                {
                    "componentname": "D",
                    "time": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
]
},


   {
    "name": "Siab",
    "value": "siab",
    "task": [
        {
            "taskname": "promobox",
            "component": [
                {
                    "componentname": "E",
                    "time": "20"
      },
                {
                    "componentname": "F",
                    "time": "10"
      }
    ]
  },

        {
            "taskname": "newswire",
            "component": [
                {
                    "componentname": "G",
                    "time": "20"
      },
                {
                    "componentname": "H",
                    "time": "10"
      }
    ]
  },
        {
            "taskname": "video",
            "component": [
                {
                    "componentname": "I",
                    "time": "20"
      },
                {
                    "componentname": "J",
                    "time": "10"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
]
```

First two dropdowns works fine. Once I select a platform from the first dropdown, second dropdown populates with the relevant tasknames. But once I select a taskname from the second dropdown, third dropdown does show irrelevant data. I can't figure out what's wrong I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the major problem you have is `jsonData = result` during the ajax request. All ajax requests are asynchronous by default, hence, every data produced from it is mostly non-existent after the request completion. So your best bet will be to pass `result` to the HTML DOM object during the request.

```
$.getJSON('tasks.json', function(result) {
$('#platform').data('jsonData',result);//Assign Json data to data object of platform id

$.each(result, function(i, platform) {
platforms += "<option value='" +
  platform.name +
  "'>" +
  platform.name +
  "</option>";
});
$('#platform').html(platforms);
});
```